# IBM Watson Tutorial Retrieve and Rank

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

I am student at Marist College working on creating our own small Watson retrieve and rank. I have been using this tutorial page https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/tutorial.html. While going through the tutorial I ran into a problem. When it came to importing the cranfield.json file, I received an error message.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaIK6.jpg "error message"

The above image shows the error I received. At the top of the picture is me creating the watson collection. After that I received a message saying it worked. After that I tried importing the cranfield.json file. Then underneath of that is the error message I received.

If someone can help me determine what caused that, whether it was me or something involving the .json file would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Please do not provide code and error messages in image format

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the IBM Watson API, but RESTful API conventions tend to dictate a 404 response when a collection or resource does not exist.

Your "name" query parameter in the first request was "example_**collections**", meaning that you created a collection with that name. In your second request you're posting to "example_**collection**", which does not exist.

Either create the "example_collection" resource to match the tutorial or change your second request to use "example_collections".

From the linked tutorial, you should be able to create the "example_collection" resource via the given command:

```
$ curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}" \
  "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/solr_clusters/{solr_cluster_id}/solr/admin/collections" \
  -d "action=CREATE&name=example_collection&collection.configName=example_config";
```

replacing `{solr_cluster_id}` and your username and password appropriately.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know how I missed that so many times. Appreciate the feedback.